# Convert template from MUSTACHE syntax to LINQ syntax

Tags: c#, aspose, aspose.words

I'm writing an app on C# + Aspose.Words. Is it possible to convert word templates from MUSTACHE syntax to LINQ syntax?

Answer (score 0):

Please use following code example to achieve your requirement. Hope this helps you.

```
FindReplaceOptions options = new FindReplaceOptions();
Document doc = new Document(MyDir + "in.docx");
doc.MailMerge.UseNonMergeFields = true;
foreach (String item in doc.MailMerge.GetFieldNames())
{
 doc.Range.Replace("{{ " + item + " }}", "<<["+ item + "]>>", options);
} 

doc.Save(MyDir + "Out.docx");
```

I work with Aspose as Developer evangelist.